# How to best add portamento to a currently playing note in an app that includes AudioKit?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

How to best add portamento to a currently playing note in an app that includes AudioKit? Tried changing the note frequency, but that didn't do it unless stopped and started note again...tried that with tiny increments, but it sounded choppy.

Basically the question really is: What is the optimal way to do Roland style slides (portamento that slides a constant duration between 2 notes, regardless of distance between frequencies) between notes using Audiokit?

Already built a sequencer, so thanks in advance for best recommended solutions!